# Avoiding async/await if I know most of the time the result will be cached

Tags: c#, async-await

Which of these is the best option when working with caching in C#?

I am interested at the compiler level which of these is the most elegant / performant solution.

E.g does the .net compiler use any tricks to know that when code will run synchronously and avoid creating/running unnecessary async await code?

Option 1, Use `async/await` and use `Task.FromResult` for cached values;

```
        public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string key)
        {
            if (_cache.containsKey(key))
            {
                // 99% of the time will hit this
                return Task.FromResult(_cache.GetItem(key));
            }

            return  await _api.GetValue(key);

        }
```

Option 2, Avoid `async/await` and use something like `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` for the few times the API Endpoint will be hit.

```
        public  T GetValue<T>(string key)
        {
            if (_cache.containsKey(key))
            {
                // 99% of the time will hit this
                return _cache.GetItem(key);
            }

            return _api.GetValue(key).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }
```

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Option 1 won't compile - you either need to remove the async & the await or remove the `Task.FromResult` and just return the value.

Answer (score 4):

The official approach is to cache the `Task<T>`, and not the `T`.

This also has the advantage that if someone requests the value, you can kick off the request to fetch the value and then cache the resulting, in-progress `Task<T>`. If someone else requests the cached value before the request has completed, they're also given the same in-progress `Task<T>`, and you don't end up making two requests.

For example:

```
public Task<T> GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    // Prefer a TryGet pattern if you can, to halve the number of lookups
    if (_cache.containsKey(key))
    {
        return _cache.GetItem(key);
    }

    var task = _api.GetValue(key);
    _cache.Add(key, task);
    return task;
}
```

Note that you need to think about failure in this case: if the request to the API fails, then you'll be caching a `Task` which contains an exception. This might be what you want, but it might not be.

If for some reason you can't do this, then the official advice is to use `ValueTask<T>` for high-performance scenarios. This type has some gotchas (such as you can't await it twice), so I recommend [reading this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/07/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/). If you don't have high performance requirements, `Task.FromResult` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your first won't work. The simplest, and the one to go for most of the time is:

```
public async Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(string key)
{
  if (_cache.ContainsKey(key))
  {
    return _cache.GetItem(key);
  }

  T result = await _api.GetValueAysnc(key);
  _cache.Add(key, result);
  return result;
}
```

Or better still if possible:

```
public async Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(string key)
{
  if (_cache.TryGet(key, out T result))
  {
    return result;
  }

  result = await _api.GetValueAysnc(key);
  _cache.Add(key, result);
  return result;
}
```

This works fine and will return an already-completed task when the value was in the cache, so `await`ing it will continue immediately.

However **if** the value is in the cache much of the time **and** the method is called often enough for the extra apparatus around `async` to make a difference then you can avoid it entirely in such a case:

```
public Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(string key)
{
  if (_cache.TryGet(key, out Task<T> result))
  {
    return result;
  }

  return GetAndCacheValueAsync(string key);
}

private async Task<T> GetAndCacheValueAsync<T>(string key)
{
  var task = _api.GetValueAysnc(key);
  result = await task;
  _cache.Add(key, task);
  return result;
}
```

Here if the value is cached we avoid both the state-machine around `async` and also the creation of a new `Task<T>` since we have stored an actual `Task`. Each of these are only done in the first case.

Comment: Ideally you want to insert the in-progress `Task` into the cache before awaiting it. That way, if someone else requests the value from cache before the request has completed, they get the same in-progress `Task`. That would be a fairly easy change to make to your code. However having made that change, the `awaits` become pointless, and you might as well remove all async machinery.

Comment: @canton7 it's better in not hitting the cache twice. And `GetAndCacheValueAsync` has an `await` on the first line, though it was an error to have it `public` instead of `private`. Fixed.

Comment: @canton7 note that I do store a `Task` in the cache in the last version.

Comment: If there are two requests for the same item, where the second happens before the first completes, then you want to hit the cache twice, and not make the expensive request for the value twice.

Comment: In your last example, there's no advantage in storing a completed `Task` in the cache. You're only adding unnecessary async machinery for no gain.

Comment: @canton7 I mean it doesn't hit it once to see if it's present, and a second time to find it. In the last example I don't store a task if there is one in the cache already. (It can be useful to store a task while still underway, but that complicates matters if the task could fail, because unless that failure was always going to happen then we'd have to take it out of the cache again).

Comment: That's a fair point re failure, and I'll add it to my answer. But in your last sample, I still maintain that `result = await _api.GetValueAsync(key); _cache.Add(key, Task.FromResult(result))` is unnecessarily complex compared to `var task = _api.GetValueAsync(key); await task; _cache.Add(key, task);`

Comment: @canton7 true. An oversight. Updating.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @canton7 likewise. Of course, sometimes one has to do more work to get the result than just waiting on another task, in which case the `FromResult()` is necessary. Likewise sometimes one wants the cache to work for both sync and async in which case storing the task has a downside.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for probably is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

A implementation might be something like this:

```
public static Func<T, TResult> Memoize<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> f)
{
    var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, TResult>();
    return a => cache.GetOrAdd(a, f);
}

Measure(() => slowSquare(2));   // 00:00:00.1009680
Measure(() => slowSquare(2));   // 00:00:00.1006473
Measure(() => slowSquare(2));   // 00:00:00.1006373
var memoizedSlow = slowSquare.Memoize();
Measure(() => memoizedSlow(2)); // 00:00:00.1070149
Measure(() => memoizedSlow(2)); // 00:00:00.0005227
Measure(() => memoizedSlow(2)); // 00:00:00.0004159
```

[Source](https://www.aleksandar.io/post/memoization/)

Answer (score -2):

First of all, this calls for linking the speed rant:

https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Microoptimisations like these are usually left to the JiT. My rule of thumb is that if you **really** need that difference, then you are propably dealing with realtime programming. And for Realtime Proramming a Garbage Collected runtime like .NET was propably the wrong environment to begin with. Something with direct memory management like unsafe code - even native C++ or Assembler - would have been better.

Secondly, a task might just be the wrong tool here. Maybe what you actually want is something like [Lazy[T]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)? Or any of the 5 different Chache classes? (as with timer, there is about one for specific User Interface technology).

It is possible to use any tool for many purposes. But tasks are for Multitasking and there are better tools for caching and lazy initialisation. And Lazy[T] is even inherently Thread save.